# How to make a nested dictionary , IOS - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I am working on an iOS App with server communication. Can someone help me to build a dictionary like this.

```
{
    "api_key": "APIKey",
    "items": [{
        "item_id": "10",
                   "quantity": "10"
    }, {
        "item_id": "11",
                   "quantity": "10"
    }],
    "user_id": "UserID",
    "user_address": "address",
    "user_number": "number"

}
```

Here is my code to create JSON which produce an invalid json

```
NSMutableArray *arrayItems = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int i=0; i<[ordeArray count]; i++) {
    ItemBO *item = [ordeArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *quantity = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",item.quantity];
    NSDictionary *dic = @{@"quantity": quantity, @"item_id":item.itemID };
    [arrayItems addObject: dic];
}
NSString * userID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:USERID];
NSDictionary *mainDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:

                    APIKEY, @"api_key",
                          orderinfo.deliveryAddress , @"delivery_address",
                          orderinfo.deliveryTime , @"delivery_time",
                          orderinfo.contactNumber , @"delivery_contact",
                          arrayItems , @"items",
                          userID , @"user_id",
                          nil];
return mainDictionary;
```

Comment: actually i am unable to create this part 
"items": [{
        "item_id": "10",
                   "quantity": "10"
    }, {
        "item_id": "11",
                   "quantity": "10"
    }],

Comment: You can check my answer for that :)

Comment: I returns invalid json.

Comment: Is this issue solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create dictionary by setting key-value pair its simple mechanism for dictionary.

In your case:

You have to take one array for items with object of item dictionary like:

```
NSDictionary *dic = @{
        "item_id": "10",
                   "quantity": "10"
    };
```

Add these type of objects in NSMutableArray like:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayItems = [NSMutableArray new];
[arrayItems addObject: dic];
```

These way you can add multiple dictionaries in this array after this done you can take another dictionary which holds all above key value pair like:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dicMain = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[dicMain setValue:"APIKey" forKey:"api_key"];
[dicMain setObject:arrayItems forKey:"items"]; // add items array in dictionary
```

and so on set all key-value pair and done thats it.

Convert this dictionary into JSON data using this

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict] options:0 error:nil];
```

and set this data as request body.like this

```
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:objData];
```

Hope this might help you. :)

Comment: it returns invalid json    NSMutableArray *arrayItems = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (int i=0; i<[ordeArray count]; i++) {
        ItemBO *item = [ordeArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *quantity = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",item.quantity];
        NSDictionary *dic = @{
                              quantity: @"quantity",
                              item.itemID: @"item_id"
                              };
        [arrayItems addObject: dic];
    }

Comment: check out this line  NSDictionary *dic = @{ quantity: @"quantity", item.itemID: @"item_id" };  In this line key should be first in this format replace that with NSDictionary *dic = @{@"quantity":  quantity,  @"item_id":item.itemID };

Comment: Is application crashing or not able to get array as expected? I didnt get that exact problem. Can you please explain in some detail?

Comment: Not able to get expected json which i need to send to server. Server say invalid json since it doesnt match the above format i posted
Here is json produced
{
    "api_key" = 123;
    "delivery_address" = "redrew tweeter";
    "delivery_contact" = rererererewrewrqe;
    "delivery_time" = "09:38 AM";
    items =     (
                {
            "item_id" = 9;
            quantity = 0;
        },
                {
            "item_id" = 11;
            quantity = 0;
        }
    );
    "user_id" = 2;
}

Comment: Would you please place code in question that you use to create JSON? Did you converted this dictionary into JSON data?

Comment: Place code in question please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116244/discussion-between-ajay-gabani-and-iosgeek).

Answer (score -1):

```
NSDictionary *dic = @{
    @"api_key": @"APIKey",
    @"items": @[@{
        @"item_id": @"10",
        @"quantity": @"10"
    }, @{
        @"item_id": @"11",
        @"quantity": @"10"
    }],
    @"user_id": @"UserID",
    @"user_address": @"address",
    @"user_number": @"number"
}
```